# ORA-00926 when trying to create a Range Partition

Tags: oracle, syntax-error, partitioning, ddl, create-table

```
SQL> create table contracts_range (
  2  document_no integer not null,
  3  contract_date date,
  4  start_date date,
  5  end_date date,
  6  salary float)
  7  partition by range (contract_date)
  8  (
  9  partition contracts_jan2020 VALUE LESS THAN ('2020-01-31'),
 10  partition contracts_fen2020 VALUE LESS THAN ('2020-03-01'),
 11  partition contracts_mar2020 VALUE LESS THAN ('2020-03-31'));
```

ERROR at line 9:
ORA-00926: missing VALUES keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's "value**s** less than", in plural, not "value less than":

```sql
create table contracts_range (
document_no integer not null,
contract_date date,
start_date date,
end_date date,
salary float)
partition by range (contract_date)
(
    partition contracts_jan2020 VALUES LESS THAN ('2020-01-31'),
    -- Here -------------------------^
    partition contracts_fen2020 VALUES LESS THAN ('2020-03-01'),
    -- Here -------------------------^
    partition contracts_mar2020 VALUES LESS THAN ('2020-03-31')
    -- Here -------------------------^
);
```